# How to display checkbox on the left when change language of Android app to Arabic?

Tags: android, checkbox, settings, locale, arabic

In Settings of my Android app, I use many of checkboxPreferences. When the locale selected is English, text appears at the Left side and Check box at the right side.
Text ------------------Checkbox

When I change locale to Arabic, I want to get this format:
Checkbox---------------Text

But it keeps the same as English locale. I don't know what to do. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To take advantage of RTL layout mirroring, simply make the following changes to your app:

1. Declare in your app manifest that your app supports RTL mirroring. Add android:supportsRtl="true" to the  element in your manifest file.
2. Change all of your app's "left/right" layout properties to new "start/end" equivalents.

[For more details follow the link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use RelativeLayout as the parent layout and then add layout_alignParentStart or layout_alignParentEnd attributes for Text / Checkbox views. 
Please note, this only works from API v17 on.